# I can't use minted which has a backslash in parameter, in \section

Tags: minted

Win 11 22H2,
TeXLive 2022, `minted` package: v2.6, `pygments`: 2.11.2

and here is my mwe:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
  \section{\mintinline{text}{section}}
  \mintinline{text}{\0}

  % \section{\mintinline{text}{\0}}
\end{document}
```

after `pdflatex -shell-escape`, I got

[image]

However after I uncomment the second `\section`, I got an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...endcsname }\fi \mintinline {text}{\0
                                                  }}{\thepage }{}\protected@...
l.6   \section{\mintinline{text}{\0}}
```

why would this happen?

Comment: The manual says to `\mintlinline`: “The command has been carefully crafted so that in most cases it will function correctly when used inside other commands.” (And your example does work in a `\footnote`, too.) It seems this is the case were it doesn't. It looks like the possible table of contents entry is the troublemaker since `\section[toc]{\mintinline{text}{\0}}` works and so will `\section[\mintinline{text}{\protect\0}]{\mintinline{text}{\0}}`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work with the development version of `minted` on [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/). You can download the development version of `minted.sty` and place that in the same directory as your document (or replace the existing `minted.sty`). The upcoming version of `minted` completely reimplements `\mintinline` so that it is more robust in these sorts of situations and also works with `hyperref` bookmarks.